# the requested url not found on server Ubuntu

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using lamp server and triying to write a controller function called send.php as below:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Send extends CI_Controller {  
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('test');
}   
}
```

test.php in view folder has the following content:

```
echo 'Hello';
```

this is location of my project folder :
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/demos/CodeIgniter/';

content of my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Deny from all
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demos/CodeIgniter/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

When i try to call http://localhost/demos/CodeIgniter/send i am getting the following error:

```
The requested URL /demos/CodeIgniter/send was not found on this 
server.Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Kindly Help me in this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-codeigniter-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-cloud-server

Comment: Use ucfirst for controller file name (i.e. `Send.php`).